# external html and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, css-position

I found this script here on SO and I've been trying to implement it into my project however I'm still new to jQuery and need a little help.

This is the script: http://jsfiddle.net/9erk2/

I'm trying to get this effect but on an externally loaded html div section and it's not working.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the fact that the div doesn't exist on load so I need to use the .live() method. Is this right, how would I go about doing this.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what effect do you mean?

Comment: @CoreyRS I mean, I'm trying to get the sidebar to change it's position to fixed when it hits the top of the window. But as this is happening in an externally loaded html section, I think I need to alter the code to include the .live() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in conjunction with the css and html code provided in the fiddle.

```
<script>
    $window.delegate("#divID", "scroll", function(event){
        scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
        topPosition = Math.max(0, sidebarTop - scrollTop),
        topPosition = Math.min(topPosition, (footerTop - scrollTop) - sidebarHeight);
        $sidebar.css('top', topPosition);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: No luck. What were you trying to do?

Comment: the delegate event binds the function to all matching elements that are on the page now and in the future, so i was seeing if it would attach the event to the dynamically loaded page as it should.

Comment: Thanks, I've been reading up on it but this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone let me know why?
 ` $window = $(window),
   $sidebar = $(".sidebar"),
   sidebarTop = $sidebar.position().top,
   sidebarHeight = $sidebar.height(),
   $footer = $(".footer"),
   footerTop = $footer.position().top,
   $sidebar.addClass('fixed');

   $window.on("scroll", function(event) {
      scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
      topPosition = Math.max(0, sidebarTop - scrollTop),
      topPosition = Math.min(topPosition, (footerTop - scrollTop) - sidebarHeight);
      $sidebar.css('top', topPosition);
   });`